# Using Single Domain SSL and Wildcard SSL in parallel on different IP addresses

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have 2 different IIS websites on different IP addresses. One is abc.example.com and another is *.example.com
I have a single domain SSL certificate on abc.example.com and now considering putting a wildcard SSL on *.example.com

Will the wildcard SSL override the single domain SSL even if they have separate DNS entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They'll have no effect on each other whatsoever.